# How to use string array to plot Y axis in Livechart , c# , windowform

Tags: c#, .net, charts, livecharts

To plot y axis , Livechart have this code

```
cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(new Axis
            {
                Labels = new[] { "Maria", "Susan", "Charles", "Frida" }
            });
```

if i have string array , how do i use it here?

[image]

Comment: Your are actually using a string array here, right? Or maybe you should explain your question more

Comment: Maria, Susan, Charles, Frida  are strings, i wanted to pass string array in place of them.

Comment: So you mean a 2-dimentional array of strings?

Comment: no just one dimentional, i'm not good in c# .net

Comment: `new[] { "Maria", "Susan", "Charles", "Frida" }` **is** an array of strings